# Upstream Message in response to downstream message in Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to send both upstream and downstream messages using Firebase Cloud Messaging. I am using sleekXmpp python library to implement an app server which receives the upstream messages.

What I want to do is send a downstream message and then wait till I get a response in the form of an upstream message. Right now, I only get an ACK message from FCM, in response to my downstream message. Later, the upstream message is received independent of the downstream.